# Java - user input - loop on error

Tags: java, python, loops, while-loop, nan

Here is my Java code:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) { // forever loop
    try {
        System.out.print("Please type a value: "); // asks user for input
        double n = userInput.nextDouble(); // gets user input as a double
        break; // ends if no error
    }
    catch (Throwable t) { // on error
        System.out.println("NaN"); // not a number
    }
}
```

You can see what this is supposed to do from the comments.

But when I enter in something that's not a number, this happens:

```
Please type a value: abc
NaN
Please type a value: NaN
Please type a value: NaN
Please type a value: NaN
Please type a value: NaN
Please type a value: NaN
Please type a value: NaN
```

and so on until I force stop it.

In Python I would just do this:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = float(raw_input("Please type a value: "))
        break
    except Exception:
        print "NaN"
```

How do I do this in Java?
I've tried using a `do while`.

Comment: Don't catch `Throwable` but the specific `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: Aside: in Python you should probably use `ValueError` rather than `Exception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (true) { // forever loop
    try {
        scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Please type a value: "); // asks user for input
        double n = userInput.nextDouble(); // gets user input as a double
        break; // ends if no error
    }
    catch (Throwable t) { // on error
        System.out.println("NaN"); // not a number
    }
}
```

you should use scanner class inside the while loop then only it will ask next input value if the given input value is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Call  the [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method in `catch` block.

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.
>
> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a
>   line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line
>   to skip if no line separators are present.

```
 catch (InputMismatchException t) { // on error
    userInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println("NaN"); // not a number
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
double n;
boolean is_valid;

do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Please type a value: ");
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = kbd.nextDouble();
        is_valid = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("NaN"); 
        is_valid = false;
    }
} 
while (!is_valid);
```

Answer (score 0):

As above ,
You can change it like this:

```
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) { // forever loop
        try {
            System.out.print("Please type a value: "); // asks user for input
            double n = userInput.nextDouble(); // gets user input as a double
            break; // ends if no error
        }
        catch (Throwable t) { // on error
            System.out.println("NaN"); // not a number
            userInput.nextLine();
        }
    }
```